# Removing index.php from CodeIgniter URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I'm struggling with removing the 'index.php' part of my CodeIgniter URL.
I'm using CodeIgniter version 3.1.2. I've followed all steps on other questions about this:

- Changed `$config['index_page'] = 'index.php'` to `$config['index_page'] = ''`
- Changed `$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO'` to `$config['uri_protocol']   = 'REQUEST_URI'`
- Added a .htaccess file in the root folder of my project with the following code:

`RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]`

However when I try to access my site, I get the following error code.

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /Toneel/Site/index was not found on this server.

The rewrite module is turned on in my Apache Server. 
Can anyone help me out with this issue?

Comment: Add RewriteBase /your_project_name after RewriteEngine On when running at localhost and just RewriteBase / when you upload the code to a server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This setting worked for me.

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  #RewriteBase /

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

To allow overriding htaccess in Apache Configuration you have to edit and change `/apache2.conf` file to

```
AllowOverride All
```

And restart server.

Comment: I think the AllowOverride All was the issue. I changed it to All and the error changed from "Not Found" to: Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /Toneel/Site/index on this server.

Comment: My Apache error logs say the following: `Options FollowSymLinks and SymLinksIfOwnerMatch are both off, so the RewriteRule directive is also forbidden due to its similar ability to circumvent directory restrictions `

Comment: Which Operating system you are using?

Comment: Windows 10 Professional

Answer (score 1):

Try this code in .htaacess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$1 [PT,L]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this code gives the same error result. I've tried about every possible .htaccess code I could find and none of them work

Comment: after rewrite module turned on did you restart server @Yaniiick

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /yourfolderhere/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it works with:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /project-name

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

** Important, this should be in an .htaccess file in the root of your project.

In *config* should be like this:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://your-url-here/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```